# setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(false) scrollbar does not move at all?

Tags: android

I have a listview with different adapters and views added to it. The adapter is a MergeAdapter (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge).

Smooth scrolling doesn't work well (as expected), so I've set:

```
getListView().setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(false);
```

but when disabled, the scrollbar behaves strangely - it just stays locked to the top of the screen, and when I scroll, it just changes transparency, never moves.

Any idea why the not-smooth scrolling would be behaving badly? The actual content itself scrolls just fine.

Thanks